# Regexp to get asterisk followed by a text from a string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am reading from a Text file that might have

```
id date       amt     msg
1  06/03/2021 45      *Upload
2  06/03/2021 34      *Error
```

Encountered Errors :1

I need a regexp to get only records with *Error msg from the file .

I tried `^[\**+Error]` this gets me the Encountered errors line too.

Comment: Do you mean to use `[*]Error`?

Comment: I edited to the syntax i tried

Comment: Did you use `WHERE msg REGEXP '^[*]Error'`? Or `WHERE msg LIKE '*Error%'`?

Comment: ^[*]Error' worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... to get only records with *Error msg

If that's so, you don't need regular expressions. `instr` does it well.

```
SQL> with test (id, msg) as
  2    (select 1, '*Upload' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '*Error'  from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Encountered Errors: 1' from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where instr(msg, '*Error') > 0;

        ID MSG
---------- ---------------------
         2 *Error

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using baseline regular expressions, you're looking for something more like `\*Error`. That escapes the asterisk (which is a special character in regex). In future, you can also use a site like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex, find errors, and see what exactly it does.